# Write in StringBuilder - a value that is not char

Tags: java

I do not usually ask here.
I have a problem with the code I wrote down - I built a compression code - implementation of LZ77.
Everything works in code - when I use files that are based on ascii text in English.

When I use a bmp file - which works differently from a plain text file - I have a problem.

In a text file - I can write the character as it is - it works.
In the bmp file - when I try to compress it - I come across characters that are not English text letters - so I can not compress the file

That I'm trying to write a letter in English into a String builder it works - but in other characters - I can not write them inside the stringBuilder - as I try to write them - it performs null.

[image]
[image]

code:

main:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String inPath = "C:\\Users\\avraam\\Documents\\final-assignment\\LZ77\\Tiny24bit.bmp";
        String outPath = "C:\\Users\\avraam\\Documents\\final-assignment\\LZ77\\encoded.txt";
        String decompressedPath = "C:\\Users\\avraam\\Documents\\final-assignment\\LZ77\\decoded.bmp";
        int windowSize = 512;
        int lookaheadBufferSize = 200;
        LZ77 compress = new LZ77(inPath,outPath,windowSize,lookaheadBufferSize);
        compress.compress();
        LZ77 decompress = new LZ77(outPath,decompressedPath,windowSize,lookaheadBufferSize);
        decompress.decompress();
        System.out.println("DONE!");
    }
}
```

LZ77

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class LZ77 {
    private String inPath = null;
    private String outPath = null;
    private File inFile;
    private File outFile;
    private final int windowSize;
    private final int lookaheadBufferSize;  
    private final int searchBufferSize;
    private int nextByteIndex = 0;
    private int nextBitIndex = 0;
    private int currentSearchBufferSize = 0;
    private int currentLookaheadBufferSize = 0;
    private int appendToWindowBuffer = 0;
    private byte[] source = null;
    
    public LZ77(String inPath,String outPath,int windowSize,int lookaheadBufferSize) throws IOException
    {
        this.inPath = inPath;
        this.outPath = outPath;
        this.inFile = new File(inPath);
        this.outFile = new File(outPath);
        this.windowSize = windowSize;
        this.lookaheadBufferSize = lookaheadBufferSize;
        this.searchBufferSize = windowSize - lookaheadBufferSize;
        this.source = Files.readAllBytes(inFile.toPath());
    }
    public void compress() throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder dictionary = new StringBuilder();
        bufferInitialize(dictionary);
        StringBuilder compressed = new StringBuilder();     
        encode(dictionary,compressed);
        addSizeBitsMod64(compressed);
        //System.out.println(compressed);
        writeFile(compressed);      
    }
    public void bufferInitialize(StringBuilder dictionary)
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < lookaheadBufferSize; i++) {
            if(source.length>nextByteIndex) {
                dictionary.append((char)Byte.toUnsignedInt(source[nextByteIndex]));
                nextByteIndex++;
                currentLookaheadBufferSize++;               
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void encode(StringBuilder dictionary,StringBuilder compressed)
    {
        while(currentLookaheadBufferSize > 0)
        {
            Match match = findMatch(dictionary);
            WriteMatch(compressed,match.offset,match.length,dictionary.charAt(currentSearchBufferSize + match.length));
            appendToWindowBuffer = increaseBuffer(match.length);
            appendBuffer(dictionary);
        }
    }
    public Match findMatch(StringBuilder dictionary)
    {
        Match match= new Match(0,0, "");
        String matchedString = null;
        int offset;
        int matchLookAheadIndex = currentSearchBufferSize;
        if(!haveAnyMatch(dictionary))
        {
        }
        else {
            matchedString = "" + dictionary.charAt(matchLookAheadIndex);
            offset = findMatchIndex(dictionary,matchedString);
            while(offset != -1 && matchLookAheadIndex < dictionary.length() - 1)
            {
                match.SetLength(match.length + 1);
                match.SetOffset(offset);
                match.SetValue(matchedString);
                matchLookAheadIndex++;
                matchedString +=dictionary.charAt(matchLookAheadIndex);
                offset = findMatchIndex(dictionary,matchedString);
            }
        }
        return match;
        
    }
    public int findMatchIndex(StringBuilder dictionary,String value)
    {
        int stringLength = value.length();
        String tmpMatch = null;
        int offsetMatch;
        for (int i = currentSearchBufferSize - 1; i >=0; i--) 
        {
            tmpMatch = dictionary.substring(i, i +stringLength );
            offsetMatch = currentSearchBufferSize - i;
            if(tmpMatch.equals(value))
            {
                return offsetMatch;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public boolean haveAnyMatch(StringBuilder dictionary)
    {
        if (currentSearchBufferSize == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!isExistInSearchBuffer(dictionary,dictionary.charAt(currentSearchBufferSize)))   
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean isExistInSearchBuffer(StringBuilder dictionary, char isCharAtDictionary)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSearchBufferSize; i++) {
            if(dictionary.charAt(i) == isCharAtDictionary)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int increaseBuffer(int matchLength)
    {
        return 1 + matchLength;
    }
    public int findBitSize(int decimalNumber) {
        if(decimalNumber >= 256)
        {
            return 16;
        }
        else
        {
            return 8;
        }
    }
    public void convertStringToBitSet(StringBuilder compressed,BitSet encodedBits)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < compressed.length(); i++) {
            if(compressed.charAt(i)==1)
            {
                encodedBits.set(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public BitSet ConvertToBits(StringBuilder compressed)
    {
        BitSet encodedBits = new BitSet(compressed.length());
        int nextIndexOfOne = compressed.indexOf("1", 0);
        while( nextIndexOfOne != -1)
        {
            encodedBits.set(nextIndexOfOne);
            nextIndexOfOne++;
            nextIndexOfOne = compressed.indexOf("1", nextIndexOfOne);
        }       
        return encodedBits;
    }
    public void writeFile(StringBuilder compressed) throws IOException
    {
        BitSet encodedBits = new BitSet(compressed.length());
        encodedBits = ConvertToBits(compressed);
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(this.outPath);
        ObjectOutputStream objectWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(writer);
        objectWriter.writeObject(encodedBits);
        objectWriter.close();
    }
    public void appendBuffer(StringBuilder dictionary)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < appendToWindowBuffer && i < source.length; i++) {
            if(ableDeleteChar(dictionary))
            {
                dictionary.deleteCharAt(0);
            }
            if(nextByteIndex<source.length)
            {
                char nextByte = (char)Byte.toUnsignedInt(source[nextByteIndex]);
                dictionary.append(nextByte);
                nextByteIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentLookaheadBufferSize--;
            }
            if(currentSearchBufferSize < searchBufferSize)
            {
                currentSearchBufferSize++;
            }
        }
        appendToWindowBuffer = 0;
    }
    public void WriteMatch(StringBuilder compressed,int offset, int length, char character)
    {
        /*int offsetBitSizeCheck, lengthBitSizeCheck;
        offsetBitSizeCheck = findBitSize(offset);
        lengthBitSizeCheck = findBitSize(length);
        */
        String offsetInBits = writeInt(offset);
        String LengthInBits = writeInt(length);
        String characterInBits = writeChar(character);
        String totalBits = offsetInBits + LengthInBits + characterInBits;
        compressed.append(totalBits);
        //compressed.append("<"+ offset + ","+ length +","+ character + ">");
        System.out.print("<"+ offset + ","+ length +","+ character + ">");
    }
    public String writeInt(int decimalNumber)
    {
        int BitSizeCheck = findBitSize(decimalNumber);
        StringBuilder binaryString = new StringBuilder();
        binaryString.append(convertNumToBinaryString(decimalNumber));
        while (binaryString.length() < BitSizeCheck)
        {
            binaryString.insert(0, "0");
        }
        if(BitSizeCheck == 8)
        {
            binaryString.insert(0, "0");
        }
        else
        {
            binaryString.insert(0, "1");
        }       
        return binaryString.toString();
    }
    public String convertNumToBinaryString(int decimalNumber)
    {   
        return Integer.toString(decimalNumber, 2);
    }
    public String writeChar(char character)
    {
        StringBuilder binaryString = new StringBuilder();
        binaryString.append(convertNumToBinaryString((int)character));
        while (binaryString.length() < 8)
        {
            binaryString.insert(0, "0");
        }
        return binaryString.toString();
    }
    public boolean ableDeleteChar(StringBuilder dictionary)
    {
        if(dictionary.length() == windowSize )
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(currentLookaheadBufferSize < lookaheadBufferSize)
        {
            if(currentSearchBufferSize == searchBufferSize)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void addSizeBitsMod64(StringBuilder compressed)
    {
        int bitsLeft = compressed.length()%64;
        String bitsLeftBinary = writeInt(bitsLeft);
        compressed.insert(0, bitsLeftBinary);
    }
    public void decompress () throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        BitSet source = readObjectFile();
        //System.out.println(source.toString());
        StringBuilder decompress = new StringBuilder ();        
        int bitSetLength = findLengthBitSet(source);
        decode(decompress,bitSetLength,source);     
        writeDecode(decompress);
    }
    public BitSet readObjectFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(this.inPath);
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        BitSet restoredDataInBits = (BitSet) objectInput.readObject();
        objectInput.close();
        return restoredDataInBits;
    }
    public void decode(StringBuilder decompress, int bitSetLength,BitSet source)
    {
        System.out.println("decode: ");
        System.out.println();
        while(nextBitIndex < bitSetLength)
        {
            Match match = convertBitsToMatch(source);
            //System.out.print("<"+ match.offset + ","+ match.length +","+ match.value + ">");
            addDecode(decompress, match);
        }
    }
    public void addDecode(StringBuilder decompress, Match match)
    {
        int RelativeOffset;
        char decodeChar;
        
        if(match.length == 0 && match.offset == 0)
        {
            decompress.append(match.value); 
        }
        else
        {   
            RelativeOffset = decompress.length() - match.offset;
            System.out.println(RelativeOffset);
            for (int i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
                decodeChar = decompress.charAt(RelativeOffset);
                decompress.append(decodeChar);
                RelativeOffset++;
            }
            decompress.append(match.value);
        }
    }
    public Match convertBitsToMatch(BitSet source)
    {
        int offset;
        int length;
        char character;
        if(source.get(nextBitIndex) == false)
        {
            nextBitIndex++;
            offset = findOffsetLengthMatch(8,source);
        }
        else
        {
            nextBitIndex++;
            offset = findOffsetLengthMatch(16,source);
        }
        if(source.get(nextBitIndex) == false)
        {
            nextBitIndex++;
            length = findOffsetLengthMatch(8,source);
        }
        else
        {
            nextBitIndex++;
            length = findOffsetLengthMatch(16,source);
        }
        
        character = findCharacterMatch(source);
        //System.out.println("offset: " + offset + " length: " + length);
        Match match = new Match(length,offset,""+character);
        System.out.print("<"+ match.offset + ","+ match.length +","+ match.value + ">");
        return match;
    }
    public int findOffsetLengthMatch(int index, BitSet source)
    {
        StringBuilder offsetLengthBinary = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if(source.get(nextBitIndex) == false)
            {
                offsetLengthBinary.append('0');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                offsetLengthBinary.append('1');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
        }
        int offsetLengthDecimal = convertBinaryStringToDecimal(offsetLengthBinary);
        //System.out.println("problem here: " + offsetLengthDecimal + " the binary is : " + offsetLengthBinary);
        return offsetLengthDecimal;
    }
    public char findCharacterMatch(BitSet source)
    {
        StringBuilder charBinary = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if(source.get(nextBitIndex) == false)
            {
                charBinary.append('0');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                charBinary.append('1');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
        }
        char charDecimal = (char)convertBinaryStringToDecimal(charBinary);
        return charDecimal;
    }
    public int findLengthBitSet(BitSet source)
    {
        StringBuilder lengthBinary = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(source.get(i) == false)
            {
                lengthBinary.append('0');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                lengthBinary.append('1');
                nextBitIndex++;
            }
        }
        int lengthModule = convertBinaryStringToDecimal(lengthBinary);
        int lengthNotUsed = 64 - lengthModule;
        int fullLength = source.size() - lengthNotUsed + 9 ;
        return fullLength;
    }
    public int convertBinaryStringToDecimal(StringBuilder lengthBinary)
    {
        int length = Integer.parseInt(lengthBinary.toString(), 2);
        //System.out.println("length: " + length + "lengthBinary: " + lengthBinary);
        return length;
    }
    public void writeDecode (StringBuilder decompress) throws IOException
    {
        Writer write = new FileWriter(this.outFile);
        write.write(decompress.toString());
        write.close();
    }
}
```

Match

```
public class Match {
    protected int length;
    protected int offset;
    protected String value;
    
    public Match(int length, int offset, String value)
    {
        this.length=length;
        this.offset=offset;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public void SetOffset(int offset) { this.offset = offset; }
    public void SetLength(int length) { this.length = length; }
    public void SetValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
    public void AddValue(char value) { this.value += value; }
    
    public void Reset()
    {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.length = 0;
        this.value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you are using `String`;  BMP's are not `String`. They are `byte[]`. You should use that and implement your algorithm to accept `byte[]`. Note that `String` can easily be converted to `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, to be honest I am quite confused, could you please elaborate a little more, I'm afraid I did not understand in depth why bmp files do not work

Comment: BMP are binary files, not text. IIRC LZ77 has different algorithms for text vs binary. You should probably also implement both and based on the leading bytes of the input decide which way to go.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I do not understand the point. bmp are byte-based files. Text files are based on char - ascii.

Why does it actually work on text files only?

Comment: Putting it simply, the concept of `String` and `BMP` should never both be in the same program.

Comment: It's very frustrating to me that I do not understand this little problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220015/discussion-between-masterhaham-and-bohemian).